# Using Set-DnsClientServerAddress on remote endpoint with string array addresses not setting correctly

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

I remotely try to set the DNS server addresses by, passing the Invoke-Command a string array of DNS server IP addresses as an argument.

This code only sets the first address (10.1.1.2)

```
$dnsIPCollection = @("10.1.1.2", "10.1.1.2")
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $serverNameHere -ScriptBlock { param($dnsIPCollection) Get-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceIndex 12 -AddressFamily IPv4 | Set-DnsClientServerAddress -ServerAddresses $dnsIPCollection } -Credential $creds -ArgumentList $dnsIPCollection
```

Now, if I try the following code, It sets both IP addresses

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $serverNameHere -ScriptBlock { Get-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceIndex 12 -AddressFamily IPv4 | Set-DnsClientServerAddress -ServerAddresses ("10.1.1.2", "10.1.1.2") } -Credential $creds
```

If I execute the following code from the remote server, it also sets both IP addresses

```
$dnsIPCollection = @("10.1.1.2", "10.1.1.2")
Set-DnsClientServerAddress -ServerAddresses $dnsIPCollection
```

I'm not sure if this is a bug or I'm doing something wrong. According to the ServerAddresses parameter [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsclient/set-dnsclientserveraddress?view=winserver2012r2-ps), the data type is `String[]`.

Is anyone able to share some insight on my observations?

My $PSVersionTable output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you're passing your `-ArgumentList $dnsIPCollection` to `Invoke-Command` - you're expecting it to pass the whole array as a single argument, but PowerShell is exploding it out into a list of arguments.

It's basically doing this:

```bsh
PS> $myArgs = @("10.1.1.x", "10.1.1.y")
PS> Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { param( $p1, $p2 )
    write-host "p1 = '$p1'"
    write-host "p2 = '$p2'"
} -ArgumentList $myArgs
```

which gives the output

```
p1 = '10.1.1.x'
p2 = '10.1.1.y'
```

Except that your script block only declares one parameter so it only receives the first value in the array of arguments - you're effectively only passing `$p1` into `Set-DnsClientServerAddress`.

If you want your array to be passed into your script block as a single argument then you need to wrap it in another array so that *your* array becomes `$p1` when PowerShell explodes the `-ArgumentList`:

```bsh
$myArgs = @("10.1.1.x", "10.1.1.y")
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { param( $p1 )
    write-host "p1 = '$p1'"
} -ArgumentList @(, $myArgs )
```

This now outputs:

```
p1 = '10.1.1.x 10.1.1.y'
```

Hopefully that helps - I'll leave applying this back into your original question as an exercise for the reader, but leave a comment if you get stuck doing it :-).

**Update**

Just to labour the point, the *reason* PowerShell explodes the argument list might be more obvious with an example with meaningful variable names:

```bsh
PS> Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { param( $username, $password )
    write-host "username = '$username'"
    write-host "password = '$password'"
} -ArgumentList @( "myUsername", "myPassword" )
```

Your example where only one IP address is being set is pretty much the same as this:

```bsh
PS> Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { param( $username )
    write-host "username = '$username'"
} -ArgumentList @( "myUsername", "myPassword" )
```

And then it should be easy to see why your second IP address isn't being set - your array of IP addresses is being treated as a list of arguments rather than a single array argument...

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, in your first example Invoke-Command is basically taking my string array and treating it as if I was splatting? Or a collection of arguments vs a single argument

Comment: This seems counter-intuitive but I  understand the behavior now that you pointed it out. I just tested it and you're right. Is it just me or does @(, $myArgs) look ugly?

Comment: @HiTech - I've added a small update to maybe make it a bit more intuitive. And yeah, I think ```@(, $myArgs )``` is a bit ugly too :-)